# is it legal for another site to skim the serverfault feed

Tags: discussion

I was doing a google search on something and found the [Admin's Goodies](http://adminsgoodies.com/) site seems to be a live (not from the quarterly creative-commons dump, there are [items](http://adminsgoodies.com/is-clearing-the-ecn-bits-from-the-ip-tos-header-considered-harmfull/) less than a day old) feed of answered SF questions.

I know that there are plenty of sites that do this with Wikipedia, and their license allows it, but I was a bit surprised to see this being done with a StackExchange site, and looking at the [terms and conditions](http://stackexchange.com/legal) it doesn't seem this would be legal unless they had a license agreement or were using the quarterly CC dump.

Am I missing something, is this legal, or a clear case of infringement?

Comment: Side note, while the license you link to states that others aren't allowed to use SE content without express permission, but every page is tagged with a License Anchor linked to the CC By SA license. A lawyer would have to hash out which license takes precedence since they're conflicting...

Comment: There are very good reasons why we close licensing questions. The main one applies here as well: We are not lawyers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, it is legal if you do it right. There is a Meta.stackoverflow question that goes into some of the details, and gives a list of sites that do such:

[Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)

That's an edge-case, though likely infringing. I'll poke some of the SE people who check into these things.

Edit: Looks like a bad site. [Reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121253/131633).